# how to get value from two table using join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function user_data_vi($email)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('client');
    $this->db->join('payments', "payments.email = $email");

    $q= $this->db->get();

    return $q->result(); 
}
```

above code are my model and method `user_data_vi` I have two table `client` and another `payments` in both table `email` field is common now I want to retrieve data from database first table have user information and `payment table` have payment info get information both table data using email field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a where condition here ,please find the modified code below

```
public function user_data_vi($email)
{
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('client');
        $this->db->join('payments', "payments.email = client.email");
        $this->db->where('client.email',$email);
        $q= $this->db->get();
        return $q->result(); 
}
```

Comment: getting this error `Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation=`

Comment: please make a backup of your database and run the following commands       ALTER TABLE client CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;        ALTER TABLE payments CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: same problem noting happen

Comment: please check your tables and make sure collation are utf8_general_ci i think for client table its currently utf8_unicode_ci , you have to make them same for two tables

Comment: both table have `utf8_unicode_ci` only 'int' and `float` are not in `utf8_unicode_ci` in booth field\

Comment: will you be able to attach export of two table please

Answer (score 0):

```
public function user_data_vi($email)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('client');
    $this->db->where('client.email',$email);
    $this->db->join('payments','payments.email = client.email');
    $q= $this->db->get();
    return $q->result(); 

}
```